# How to make primary key of one table, the foreign key of same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to make primary key of one table, the foreign key of the same table?

I have table `vendors` with these attributes:

```
vendor_id,
company_name
rep_first
rep_last
referredby
```

Do I want to make `vendor_id` as the foreign key of that table?

Here is what I have tried:

```
create table vendors(
  vendor_id char(5) Not Null primary key,
  company_name varchar(255),
  rep_first varchar(255),
  rep_last varchar(255),
  referredby char(5)
);
constraint vendors_REF_FK
foreign key (referredby) references vendors(referredby)
```

Comment: What does not work specifically? Indicate your error messages or at least paste the incorrect output.

Answer (score 1):

Constraints is also part of the table and thus have to go along with table definition like

```
vendor_id char(5) Not Null primary key, 
company_name varchar(255), 
rep_first varchar(255), 
rep_last varchar(255), 
refferedby char(5),
constraint vendors_REF_FK foreign key (refferedby) references vendors(vendor_id ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `ALTER TABLE` as well

```
ALTER TABLE Vendors
ADD CONSTRAINT vendors_REF_FK FOREIGN KEY (refferedby) REFERENCES Vendors(vendor_id );
```